# expose C++ function to python

Tags: boost-python

The C++ code looks like:

```
struct A {
    A(int x, int y):a(x),b(y){}
    int a;
    int b;
};
std::vector<A> get_a(const A& a1, const A& a2);
```

And expose them to python:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Hello)
{
    using namespace boost::python;

    class_<A>("A")
        .def(init<int, int>())
        .def_readwrite("a", &A::a)
        .def_readwrite("b", &A::b);
    def("get_a", get_a);
}
```

Build those code into a hello.pyd. And call get_a in python code:

```
import hello
a1 = hello.A(1,2)
a2 = hello.A(3,4)
hello.get_a(a1, a2)
```

but this won't work:

```
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    hello.get_a(Boost.Python.class, Boost.Python.class)
did not match C++ signature:
    get_a(class A, class A)
```

I have not found useful info in boost.python doc about how to pass a self-defined object, how to do this? And I guess the return type std::vector also will not automatically deal with. How to let python's list to take the return value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expose constructor it needs to be passed to `class_` instead of `def`:

`class_<A>("A", init<int, int>())`.

`def` is to be used for additional contructors, see [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/exposing.html#tutorial.exposing.constructors).

To expose `vector<A>` use `vector_indexing_suite`.

**Complete example:**

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/suite/indexing/vector_indexing_suite.hpp>

struct A {
    A(int x, int y) :a(x), b(y) {}
    int a;
    int b;

    bool operator==(const A& data)
    {
        return this->a == data.a && this->b == data.b;
    }
};
std::vector<A> get_a(const A& a1, const A& a2)
{
    const std::vector<A> ret = { a1,a2 };
    return ret;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello) 
{
    using namespace boost::python;

    class_<std::vector<A> >("vecA")
        .def(vector_indexing_suite<std::vector<A>>())
        ;

    class_<A>("A", init<int, int>())
        .def_readwrite("a", &A::a)
        .def_readwrite("b", &A::b);
    def("get_a", get_a);
}
```

**Test script:**

```
import hello

a1 = hello.A(1,2)
a2 = hello.A(3,4)
ret = hello.get_a(a1, a2)
print "size:", len(ret)
print "values:"
for x in ret:
  print x.a, x.b
```

**Output:**

```
size: 2
values:
1 2
3 4
```